# Artistic research question - How would a road accident victim"s family be received at the emergency room? What would they be told?

Tags: hospital

I need some help with a chapter of a novel I am writing. The main character, a teenage girl, is informed by her father on the phone that her mother has been run over by a car and been taken to hospital. (Dad had of course been notified by police). Daughter then goes from the party she was at by taxi to the hospital where her father is waiting. Soon after the girl's arrival the mother will die of her injuries. In order to get the right atmosphere and make it sound right, I would like to know how the girl would be greeted by medical staff, where her father might be waiting - I imagine in the lobby or the front entrance  -  what she and her father would be told about the injuries, and where they would have to wait until told the news - is there a special quiet room, or would they just be in the lobby or general waiting room? Would they be allowed to see the mother either before or after her death? The scene takes place in the late evening, around eleven pm, in a major city. Thanks very much for your help.

Comment: A teenager takes a taxi? Okay, boomer. ;-) A teenager would take an Uber or Lyft.

Comment: @CareyGregory Maybe it's a period piece.

Comment: @BryanKrause In that case we'd certainly need to know the period.

Comment: And regardless of period, we need to know the country.

Comment: Probably better asked at https://writing.stackexchange.com/.